# SQl Express changing language

Tags: sql-server-express

How do you change the Language in SQL Express (2008) to another language like English?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this way ( e.g. for british english )

```
EXEC sp_configure 'default language', 23 
RECONFIGURE
```

Comment: Also found

execute SP_HELPLANGUAGE

display all your languages